# Make apache accept requests only if who sent requests is a domain i specified

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I currently have an apache2 server accepting api requests on the url `mydomain.com/api` and i have a client application that runs at `mydomain.com`. 
Also, in my api, one can access `mydomain.com/api/files/fileId` to get a file.
Now, in my client application, i have a page like `mydomain.com/file/fileid` which instead of directly downloading the file like the corresponding api endpoint does, it displays a page with the file information and if it is a video it has the right custom GUI to stream it. The problem is that one can access the api directly and get the file that way instead of seeing it on the website, and i want to prevent this. 
The end goal is to prevent the user from downloading the file and only serving it through my website, a little bit like youtube does ( that i know of )... 
Is this achievable with an apache configuration? Or should i completely change the way i am approaching this?
EDIT: For now i am keeping that the file can be accessed both from the api url and the website page, but if anywaone has any idea please help thanks

Comment: I think it's a duplicate like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550660/how-to-block-direct-download-file)

Comment: I dont think so. I already have authentication on these requests, my need is to prevent people from accessing the api url directly, and only allow my application to use it

Comment: then restricted to localhost, that. might be a good solve?

Comment: If i restrict the request to localhost then my web application cannot access it, since it needss to access the resource as any other user. Or at least i dont know a way to do it, but i think thats not possible

Comment: if you written this, then you should be able to do this. You can maybe also use a hidden key to allow access but that's just a thought. Remember that it exists anti leech scripts that are preventing users from knowing the real url. But serverfault is not a coding page. Stackoverflow.com would be in my mind your better choice to solve the problem in the source instead of doing and creating a workaround

Comment: I thought about using a key saved on the client but then can someone who knows some basics, navigate the js and find the key? Also, i did not know about those "leech scripts" so i will definetly look into that to see if they help my case, thanks.